# How to copy the value of one structure array to another structure array in c++

Tags: c++

I have 2 different structures. I want to copy the value of obj[i].process to n_obj[i+1].n_process, but codeblocks says invalid array assignment.But Code:

```
struct object{
char process[10];
int burst_time;
double l;
};

struct n_object{
char n_process[10];
int n_burst_time;
};

int main(){
object obj[100];
n_object n_obj[100];
int n,a,count_g=0,count_l=0,q_t,sum=0,tot_t=0,wait_t=0,g_c[100],t_t[100],w_t[100];
double l;

for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    if(q_t>obj[i].burst_time){
        sum=sum+obj[i].burst_time;
        n_obj[i+1].n_burst_time=sum;
        n_obj[i+1].n_process=obj[i].process;
    }
    else if(q_t<obj[i].burst_time){
        a=obj[i].burst_time-q_t;
        sum=q_t+sum;
        n_obj[i+1].n_burst_time=sum;
        n_obj[i+1].n_process=obj[i].process;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays, use std::vector.

Comment: If you used C++ and had `std::array<char, 10> whatever;` instead of `char whatever[10];`, your code would have compiled with no issues (running the code would be a different story).

Comment: Note that `n` is uninitialized. So `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign arrays in C++. It's one of many reasons that using arrays is a bad idea.

You have four reasonable options

1) Use `std::array`.

```
#include <array>

struct object{
    std::array<char, 10> process;
    int burst_time;
    double l;
};
```

Same change for `n_object`, now your code will compile. `std::array` works very much like a regular array but it can be assigned (among other advantages).

2) Copy the elements with `std::copy`

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(obj[i].process, obj[i].process + 10, n_obj[i+1].n_process);
```

3) Copy the elements with `memcpy`

```
#include <cstring>

memcpy(n_obj[i+1].n_process, obj[i].process, 10*sizeof(char));
```

4) Write a loop and copy the elements one by one

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    n_obj[i+1].n_process[j] = obj[i].process[j];
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a pod here.  You can use memcpy on the array.